# I want one of my users to be able to 'sudo init 5' without being asked for a passwd. How to do it?

Tags: sudo, users

I want one of my users (let's call him: pn) to be able to start X by `sudo init 5`.
I ***don't*** want to give him access to any other commands.
I read `man sudoers`, but I don't understand too much of it.
Can anyone provide a quick line to add to `/etc/sudoers` file that would do the trick?
I would be grateful eternally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `sudo visudo` and add the following line to the end of /etc/sudoers:

```
pn [hostname] = (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/init 5
```

Replace [hostname] with the output of `hostname`.

After this change, the user pn will be able to execute `sudo init 5` without a password.